# When a moderator closes a question they misunderstand

Tags: discussion

[How can Android native code target multiple processor types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412241/i-am-confused-about-native-code)

Is a perfect example of a moderator reading a wild tangent into a question, providing an unrelated answer, and then when this is pointed out, reacting by closing the question.

How do we handle this kind of (unfortunately not infrequent) problem?

Comment: It'd add a comment explaining why it should be open and also flag it with a custom reason. If you have enough rep, you can also vote to reopen.

Comment: I understand that decision. The question is pretty vaguely asked. You have made an assumption that OP is specifically asking about NDK based on Android tag. That is a probable interpretation... however forcing OP to better rephrase the question does not seem as a bad decision.

Comment: @PavelHoral - truly, the only other usage of "native" in the Android context is the occasional, somewhat mistaken way that people targeting phonegap, titatanium, html5 or other framework/javascript-in-browser layers sometimes refer to a normal java-written app.  But that is **clearly not** what this question is about - leaving the role the NDK fills as the only relevant subject, especially as the question **explicitly mentions** working directly with the actual processor.

Comment: If you think you can provide an answer in four paragraphs or less *that thoroughly addresses his level of understanding,* I'll reopen the question.  Based on your specifics, it appears to me that you would need to write an extended tutorial.

Comment: Robert, I had already provided an answer BEFORE you closed it for the first time.  The problem is that you jumped in without a real awareness of the subject matter, made a wrong assumption, and are unwilling to admit that you made a mistake.

Comment: Don't forget that when a question is closed (on hold), that's only to prevent new answers from being added. The point is for the OP to improve the question without the distraction of answers that aren't what the Asker wants.

Comment: @3524344 - the issue is that this question doesn't *need* improvement. It's quite clear to anyone with the background to answer it, and only unclear to those unfamiliar with the subject matter.

Comment: So you couldn't take 30 seconds to clean up the question a bit?  See, this is why people complain about moderators so much; they abdicate their community responsibilities, and then whine when a moderator makes their decisions for them.

Comment: "Cleaning up the question" would mean substituting my words for the posters.  I don't think that's appropriate - while there's no ambiguity there, in a case where there ws, and I eliminated it by writing *my reading* into the question itself, then I could have seriously distorted it.  Instead, by posting the correct answer and pointing out why your answer is unrelated, I at least leave you a path open to disagree.

Comment: That's a nice idea, but it doesn't work.  Questions have to stand on their own merit.  Remember, you and the OP are not the only ones seeing the post.  The entire Google community is also looking for the answer you've posted, so if you're going to make assumptions about what question was asked (and the question is marginal to begin with), you might as well write your assumptions into the question.  I daresay that's a better outcome than closing and deleting the question, because *nobody* benefits from that.

Comment: First, I'm recognizing the **facts** (such as explicit mention of directly working with the processor) of the question on a topic where I have relevant experience and expertise, not making assumptions.  But even if I were making assumptions, it would be more appropriate for me to write my "assumptions" into my answer, just as your wrote yours into your answer, and leave it up to the OP and community voting to decide which answers are or aren't relevant.

Comment: I am part of the community, and I did decide.  If you want a more desirable outcome, you have to do something different. Stack Exchange is not a debate forum, so the notion that people should have to make assumptions about questions and then vote on those assumptions makes no sense.  Real questions have real answers, both of which can be voted on their merits, not some underlying assumptions.

Answer (score 9):

As [originally asked](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23412241/revisions), you have to admit that was a pretty unclear question. They didn't even mention the fact that this was for Android (beyond the one tag) and specific to the NDK on that platform. Leading with "What is the point of native code?" didn't help, since the answer to that is a chapter in a book.

However, that wasn't the core of their question. CodesInChaos edited the question to focus it down, and I modified the title to reflect their actual question about how to deploy to multiple processors using native code. As a result, I don't believe it is too broad any longer and I've reopened it.

If you believe that a moderator or close voters have misinterpreted a question, the first thing I'd attempt would be to clarify the question itself. Beyond that, you brought this up on Meta for us to discuss and flagged the question, which is the procedure I'd recommend for something like this. It doesn't guarantee that the question will be reopened, but at least can let us review it.

Comment: This is mistaken.  First, tags are considered to be a sufficient mention, as evidenced by editing to remove them from titles being (IMHO unwisely) considered appropriate.  Second, there is simply no way that the explicit mention (in the original form of the question) of code for the actual processor can be misinterpreted by anyone familiar with the subject matter.

Comment: @ChrisStratton assuming that's true, you still leave your question open for those with only a passing familiarity to misinterpret and close the question. Clarifying it to avoid such a thing from happening is step 1.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Tags don't belong in the *title*, but that doesn't mean that the question *body* shouldn't discuss the technologies in question, in some way.

Answer (score 4):

In general you have several options, as moderator close votes do not prevent reopening (unlike moderator deletions).  So you can reopen the question.

1. Firstly, you should write a comment under the question explaining why the close reason is wrong.  Remember you might be "speaking" to individuals who might not be experts, so you need to be clear and understandable to someone who is not necessarily going to understand the details
2. Next, you should edit the question, if necessary, to eliminate any confusion.  If the moderator misunderstood the question, then maybe there is something that is unclear, confusing, or ambiguous in the question that needs addressed.  This should throw the question into the the reopen queue.
3. Once that is done, then you need to vote to reopen if you have the privileges to do so.
   This will also throw the question in the reopen queue.

Then it is just a matter of sitting and waiting, and letting the community review the question in the reopen queue and vote to reopen (presuming the agree).

Some other options, if that fails or isn't working fast enough

- Bring the question up in chat.  You might find enough users who agree with you and can vote to reopen as well, or they can explain why they think the close reason is correct.
- Open a question on Meta.  You'll find a number of users who can offer their 2 cents on the question and may also vote to reopen it.
- As a very last resort, you can flag it for moderator attention and explain in brief detail why the close reason is wrong, and why the question needs reopened.  You can point them to your comment you left in Step 1 above as well as any other relevant discussions in chat or on Meta.  If the mod agrees, they can reopen it.

Comment: In the past, when I've complained about moderator close/reopen/close differently cycles wiping out user re-open votes, I've been explicitly told that when a moderator closes something, one should not try to reopen it by voting.

Comment: That's not true at all.  If it were, the system would lock out reopen votes on moderator-closed questions.

Comment: @ChrisStratton not sure why anyone would say you shouldn't try to reopen a mod closed question.  If they didn't want the community to reopen mod closed questions, they would simply prevent reopening like they do with deletions.  This is one of the powers of the community - we can override a mod.

Comment: I was directly told by moderators here not to bother with *voting* to override a moderator, as it would not work - that only a moderator could undo that (which does, indeed seem contrary to the design intent of community involvement).  It may have been that the implication there was that moderators repeatedly changing the close reason wiping out user votes should not be considered a bug, since the view is that users should not be able to collective outvote the mods.  Unfortunately, the meta question where that advice was given has been removed, so I can't specifically point it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton you're sure it's not on http://meta.stackexchange.com? In any case, if said it was wrong because it's simply not true.

Comment: @ChrisStratton the only thing you can't do is undelete a question deleted by a mod (or a bot with mod-powers - i.e. Community).  That is possibly what you were told. Beyond that, I have only ever seen mods encourage users to override their close decisions.  This specific case is probably an exception, but more often than not, mods are responding to flags on posts and not voting on their own.

Comment: The issue was that a number of community votes accrued towards re-opening, then Robert Harvey wiped those out by changing to yet another inapplicable close reason.  Users felt this was a perversion of the process, the mods responded that we shouldn't be trying to override them with *votes* anyway.

Comment: I'd love to see that post, if you can at all find it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - For the record, I believe you're referring to the discussion here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218275/what-can-be-done-when-an-abusive-mod-closes-the-meta-thread-about-his-abuse . That involved moderator deletion of a post, which cannot be overridden by normal community votes. There were other things going on there, and the community did get that reversed and their point expressed.

Comment: @BradLarson - yes, but the comment that is really sticking in my memory from that was the "Also fwiw the toggle of close state to wipe votes thing has been standard operating procedure for literally years." subsequent disagreement that this is a problem, and advice that flagging is the only recourse.

Comment: That seems to be a misinterpretation  (or confusion) of what Charles is actually saying. He does not state one should not go against the decision of a moderator. He only states that if you directly want to appeal the action of a moderator, you can flag to have it reviewed.