# Why is it acceptable for a moderator to arbitrarily delete a compliant post?

Tags: discussion

Why is it acceptable for this to be deleted?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651219/how-to-scrape-data-from-android-apps

Where is the violation of site guidelines which would justify that?

There has been an unfortunate pattern of such behavior from Mr. Harvey.

Comment: Keep in mind that deleted comments can't be seen (unless you're a site mod).  We don't know what may or may not have been said in the commentary.  The OP may have been sufficiently inflammatory to where Robert simply said "this one is done."  Likewise, there could have been a chat between the two users that we aren't able to see.

Comment: @GlenH7 - there was no commentary other than a 3x upvoted technical analysis from me, and a question in response from the poster. If one wants to argue that the question was broad, these represented progress towards directing it.

Comment: Fair enough regarding the lack of comments.  My main point is that there can be additional channels of information that we don't have access to.

Comment: If it was deleted after 60 days instead, would that be OK?

Comment: @random - if it hadn't improved in 61 days, sure.  But there was active development going on in the two comments posted.

Comment: Because it's not a suitable question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JackManey - even if you think the original is broad, the development of the question raised in the OP's comment is certainly appropriate and answerable ("Android's protection model prevents that unless the monitoring and target apps run under the same userID").  With the post deleted, they have no chance to edit that into the question body as an improvement - that's why deletion is completely improper here.

Comment: Moderators (and those with more than 10K rep) are able to delete questions. The question was not found to be suitable for Stack Overflow. That is, quite literally, the answer to your question of why the linked question was deleted.

Comment: That's merely an explanation of the capability to modify the database.  **It is in no way a justification for *using* it in this case** - how was the post irredeemably unsuitable to the level where deletion was necessary?  IMHO, an *immediate* escalation to that is reserved only for damaging material such as spam and raving insults.

Comment: Chris - the OP can still access their question even though it's deleted, and they can still edit.  Likewise, any 10k user with a direct link can see and edit that question.  Part of [your concern](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286828/why-is-it-acceptable-for-a-moderator-to-arbitrarily-delete-a-compliant-post#comment159109_286828) isn't well founded.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit the answerable question from the OP's comment into it and flag for re-opening.

Comment: Undeleted.  BRB, VTC.

Comment: Damn that Mr. Harvey.  We should string him up by the yardarm, draw and quarter him, and then make him walk the plank.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you are hereby sentenced to watch the [tag:php] feed for a duration not less than 1 minute and not to exceed 7 days...

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOOO!

Comment: @RobertHarvey could always toss a filter on it... like [php+regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+regex)

Comment: Thankfully, it's been deleted again.

Comment: Does denying others the ability to provide help on technical programming questions make you happy?  If so, perhaps you have lost track of the reason why this site exists.

Comment: @RobertHarvey We shall throw fish at you as all four of your quarters walk the plank.

Comment: Oh, I'm quite aware of why this site exists. That's why I'm glad the aforementioned question is deleted again.

Answer (score 12):

In its current state, it should stay deleted.

It's a really broad question; to the point where it's a lightning rod for bad answers.

If you want it undeleted, it needs to be narrowed down greatly.  What sort of App do you want to extract data from (what's its name? How does it store data)? What do you know about it its surface area that would let help us know what you have access to? What sort of ways are you open to? Network Packet Sniffing? physical access to the device alone?

As written, there could be many different ways to solve this issue, and each app could have a slightly different approach. There is no "one size fits all" solution here; and that's why it's too broad.

As far as your question being deleted instead of closed -> deleted; Robert did the OP a favor there. I can only imagine the amount of downvotes they'd have gotten if we let the question go through the normal closure -> deletion process.

Sometimes we delete questions as much as a favor to the OP as it is to the community.  A deleted question can't be downvoted; and that's one less question that can harm the OP by accruing downvotes.

Comment: Question has been edited to move specific and answerable followup from the OP's comment into the main question body.   (The answer will be, no you cannot do that unless your app runs under the same userID as the one you wish to extract from, or you have a way to run code as root)

Comment: @ChrisStratton The question is still a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740969/screen-scraping-accessing-data-from-another-app-an-android-iphone-app).

Comment: IMHO, most posters would rather have a technical answer than win the popularity contest of votes.

Comment: @Lous - no, it isn't.  That question is about network data, this one is about local data.   They are *related*, but an answer to this question would not be an answer to the other one if posted there.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The point is that the question, as it stands, wouldn't actually get any answers of value.  The question is just way, way, to broad to actually get answered, so it wouldn't get answered.  It'd just get closed (or worse yet, just never responded to at all).

Comment: It's rather revisionist to  speculate that it wouldn't be responded to at all, when it already had been responded to even before you gained awareness of it.  Note that a "no that won't work either" answer has value, as it saves someone from wasting time implementing what won't work.

Answer (score 7):

After looking through the history of the question I probably would have just deleted it too. The question was too broad to begin with, and it wasn't clear to me why it wasn't a duplicate of another question. It would have been helpful to leave a comment explaining that when you reopened it. If I have to come back to a poor-quality question several times in response to flags, I'll often just delete it. Moderators are volunteers. Our time isn't compensated, so we don't like to waste a lot of it on questions that don't look like they're going to be salvageable. (The OP hadn't been back to respond to your comment for a few hours when the question was deleted.)

After reading your comments here, I do agree that the question is not an exact duplicate, so I've undeleted it. It's still fairly low-quality, but it is just barely answerable.

Answer (score 6):

The question look *way* too broad to be an appropriate SO question.

It also has a vote to close as being a computing hardware question, rather than a programming question.

Comment: I agree, but in that case, it should just be closed instead of insta-deleted.

Comment: @Mysticial Apparently Robert felt that there was no way for the author to edit it into an appropriate question,.

Comment: @Mysticial: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28651219/revisions (I know to look in revs because apparently the system had flagged it as "contested closed")

Comment: I'd argue on the close (I'd re-opened it as a non-duplicate, and it is definitely not "a computer hardware question" but the deletion is entirely illegitimate.

Comment: @BoltClock Ahahaha, I didn't see that. :)

Comment: @Mysticial: It's *always* the last place anyone thinks of looking.

Comment: @BoltClock - and  correcting an improper duplicate closure justifies deletion how?  To me it looks like Mr. Harvey's continuing inability to admit he often makes mistakes.  We are supposed to handle these things as a community, not one person wiping them from the slate.

Comment: @Chris Stratton: Yeah you'd have to ask him. I have no idea what to make of that history.

Comment: I've twice flagged it as an improper deletion, only to be ignored without explanation.  It either needs to be undeleted, **or a very sound explanation provided as to why the question is unacceptable and irredeemable**.

Comment: Technically, you've only had one of your flags rejected - your other flag was raised just minutes before you came here. But in any case, rest assured you've got the attention of at least half the moderator team now.

Comment: When we see a flag like "grossly improper deletion, clear abuse of moderation powers" (your previous one) on a downvoted post that had votes to close on it, you can see why we might potentially decline that. Particularly given [your personal history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218275/what-can-be-done-when-an-abusive-mod-closes-the-meta-thread-about-his-abuse) with [Robert](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253125/when-a-moderator-closes-a-question-they-misunderstand).

Comment: If you are going to link to example of Mr. Harvey's past misbehavior, you should take the time to understand how wrong the technical jumps-to-conlusion he claimed as justification really are.  It's that knee-jerk decisionmaking, and inability to tolerate being called on his errors which makes him abusive.

Comment: @ChrisStratton If you're going to just go off on rants then you're points aren't going to be taken seriously, regardless of their merits.